# Flash CS5 AS3 drop shadow filter won't print

Tags: flash, actionscript-3, printing, filter, dropshadow

I've tried searching quite a bit to discover why I don't seem to be able to print drop shadow filters from within Flash.  I don't have any trouble printing, but if the movieclip I want to print has or contains a drop shadow, that clip will print sans the drop shadow.

Anyone have any insight as to why this might be happening?

If you want to try it out yourself, here is the simple print code I'm using.  Just put something inside contentmc with a dropshadow and print it.

```
print_btn.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK,printContent);

function printContent(evt:MouseEvent) {
 var printJob:PrintJob = new PrintJob();

 if (printJob.start()) {

  if (content_mc.width>printJob.pageWidth) {
   content_mc.width=printJob.pageWidth;
   content_mc.scaleY=content_mc.scaleX;
  }

  printJob.addPage(content_mc);
  printJob.send();
 }
}
```

Comment: `content_mc.width=printJob.pageWidth;`
Are you sure there is place for shadow left?

Answer (score 0):

You could try [printAsBitmap](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/printing/PrintJobOptions.html#printAsBitmap), I'm not sure it would work, but it may.